# where can I vote for changes to javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods, syntax

As a newbie, I find .unshift() to be very illogical. I understand that it's complicated how some words come about.

I want to vote that the verbage is changed so that .push() adds to the 0th element, pushing the array, while .append() replaces .push as the appending mechanism.

I personally feel this will make learning javascript much more intuitive.

Is there a place to basically vote for these kinds of changes??

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to become a member of the committee that develops the latest [ECMAscript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

However it's likely you'll be outvoted, as that change would break a lot of code.